# How can I sort div elements based on inner div element content / values using javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have X amount of divs in a page, each div item represents a single product and looks like this:

```
<div class="productContainer">
<li>
    <img src="my-product-image.jpg"></a>
    <div class="productInfo">
        <h4>
            <!-- SORT ALL DIVS BASED ON A TAG CONTENT -->
            <a class="productTitleForSorting" href="product-page-link">NAME</a><br>
        </h4>
        <div class="product-price">               
            <span id="lowestPrice">PRICE:
            <!-- OR SORT ALL DIVS BY PRODUCT PRICE SPAN CONTENT -->
            <span class="productPriceForSorting">$XX.XX</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>               
</li>
</div>
```

Then I have a select list / dropdown list from where I'd like to sort the divs by price or alphabetically.

For example, let's say I have 10 divs (10 products), like the one above on a single page.  I would like to be able to sort either by title (a.productTitleForSorting content), or by price (span.productPriceForSorting) on select list change.

Any ideas how I can go about accomplishing this with Javascript / jQuery? It has to be done on the client side.

I tried using a datasort plugin, but no luck with that one, so looking for new ideas and suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend sorting and reordering the dom. If it has to be done on client side then store the javascript array and sort that. For example:

```
var items = [{price:3,name:"something"}, {price:10,name:"somethingelse"}];
```

Now use [JavaScript sort functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) to sort this and append to the dom. This is much more efficient than moving around dom objects.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the native sort function, but the thing is that you have to provide a comparison mechanism:

```
function sortByPrice(a,b){
    return $(a).find('.productPriceForSorting').text() > $(b).find('.productPriceForSorting').text();
}
```

then you can sort your elements by using:

```
$('.productContainer').sort(sortByPrice);
```

After you've sorted the elements, you need to update the html, so you should empty the product container and then append the sorted elements in the new order :

```
function reorderEl(el){
    var container = $('#productList');
    container.html('');
    el.each(function(){
        $(this).appendTo(container);
    });
}
```

Putting it all toghether :

```
reorderEl($('.productContainer').sort(sortByPrice));
```

here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/jKJc3/

Comment: Can you find the link to the jquery `sort` function docs? I read it was added in 1.3.2 but can't find it on the site.

Comment: i'm using the native javascript sort function.It's not jquery. here's an example : `[3,1,6,2,7,234,3,8].sort(function(a,b){return a>b;});`

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this, really appreciate it, especially for putting up the example on jsFiddle!

Comment: For now, this is working great for my alpha a to z sorting. But it's not working for numbers.  For example, it's sorting (asc) $11.99 - $8.75 and not $8.75 - $11.99, since I assume in text comparison 1 is before 8.  Is there a function that will sort this properly?

Comment: I was able to sort the above by using the [Number()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp) function. This works in my scenario because I have access to the raw, not formatted number (i.e. 1199 for outputted $11.99). My sortNumber function now looks like:
`function sortByPriceAsc (a,b){
    return Number( $(a).find('.productPriceForSorting').text() -   $(b).find('.productPriceForSorting').text() );
}`

Otherwise, first the $ and . (dot) for the decimal point need to be stripped from the string using JavaScript.  Or use natural array sorting.

Comment: @gion_13 - I just found out that the code does not work in Safari or IE (all versions) - same is true for the code you put up on jsFiddle.com.  I suspect it's something with the syntax of the sorting functions ...

Comment: Got it to work in Safari by returning a 1 or -1 from the sort functions.  Still no go in IE.  When you click to sort everything disappears.

Comment: I would use `container.children().detach();` instead of `container.html(')` This will keep the event listener attached to the elements

Answer (score 1):

Using something like [this sorting plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/), you just need comparator functions like:

```
function sortByTag(a, b) {
  $(a).find('a').first().text() > $(b).find('a').first().text();
}
```